# How to map table items in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I would like to learn how do we map a table item (aka row), so that I can add table rows dynamically. My table is editable and this is its structure

[image]

Here is more or less the part of the code that the rows should be mapped   :

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry : rowMap.entrySet()) {

                Integer key = entry.getKey(); 

                .....

                table.addItem(obj, key);
            }
```

Comment: I've used IndexedContainer to load tables up. See https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-container.html

Comment: @ChrisM Yes I know about Indexed Container, but here I would like to Map the rows. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

Make an array and then select items inside array.

```
table.addItem(new Object[]{"Canopus",        -0.72f}, 2);
```

Maping them this way is easier, all that's left to make a dynamic loop in order to enable dynamic row adding/removing.

Comment: Yes but my main problem after adding the rows, is how to track if something is edited (or added) in the table so that i can update it in the database.